# XCode/Swift 3: How to shift storyboard elements down/up without messing up existing constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

XCode/Swift 3

I've placed several elements (e.g. labels, text Fields) on my story board, and I've properly set all constraints.

Now I've decided that all content needs to shift down about five pixels. I can press the COMMAND + A keys to select all and then press the down arrow five times on my keyboard to shift everything. However, that messes up all of my existing constraints!

How can I shift everything down five pixels and preserve my constraints?

I'm very new to iOS programming, so thanks for your patience for what must be a very easy question for some of you!

Comment: You will have to manually change the required constraints. I personally don't like making Xcode update the constraints as somehow it always makes them worse(maybe its just me).

Comment: please post screenshot of your UI

Answer (score 1):

after you shifted down all your items (like you've done)

there is a button with which you can update all constraints

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you shift elements down it will cause the constraints to update accordingly. You should update all constraints, an easy way to do it is by selection the following option:

[image]

Select "Update constraints" and make sure you select "Apply to all views in container".

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it, First you have shifted all these downs now on storyboard left side there is a Document Outline Bar, on that your storyboard has a yellow arrow, click that and you will see all the shifted objects are presents with their properties. Click them one by one and and select

> Update Constraints

This will set your constraints as you updated.